# How to clear all data in MIMEBase (email module)

Tags: python, email

so i have this code:

```
import smtplib
from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.MIMEBase import MIMEBase
from email.MIMEText import MIMEText
from email.Utils import COMMASPACE, formatdate
from email import Encoders
import os

def sendMail(to, subject, text, files=[],server="smtp.gmail.com:587"):
    assert type(to)==list
    assert type(files)==list
    fro = "psaoflamand@live.com>"

    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg['From'] = fro
    msg['To'] = COMMASPACE.join(to)
    msg['Date'] = formatdate(localtime=True)
    msg['Subject'] = subject

    msg.attach( MIMEText(text) )
    a=0
    username = 'psaoflamand@gmail.com'  
    password = 'pass'  

    # The actual mail send  


    smtp = smtplib.SMTP(server)
    smtp.starttls()  
    smtp.login(username,password)

    for file in files:
        a+=1
        print a
        part = MIMEBase('application', "octet-stream")
        part.set_payload( open(file,"rb").read() )
        Encoders.encode_base64(part)
        part.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="%s"'
                       % os.path.basename(file))
        msg.attach(part)
        if a==21:
            smtp.sendmail(fro, to, msg.as_string() )
            a=0
            print 'sent'


    smtp.quit()


sendMail(
        ["psaoflamand@live.com"],
        "hello","cheers",
        ["Thousands of one megabyte files"]
```

in this code it sends 21 files at a time to avoid going over the limit of gmail messages. But the probleme is that the data in MIMEBase stays... my question is is there a way to delete all data in the MIMEBase? Im sorry that the indentation is wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your problem is that you:

1. Create a `msg`.
2. Append 21 files to `msg`.
3. Send it.
4. Append 21 more files, so that it has 42 files now attached.
5. Send it again; this second message is twice as large as the first.
6. Append 21 more files, bringing the total to 63.
7. Send it again; it's getting pretty huge now.
8. And so forth.

When `a==21` you should start over with a fresh `msg` object instead of continuing to append more and more files to the old one.

Alternately, you could try removing the 21 attachments already there before attaching the new ones; but just starting over might be simpler, since you already have the code in place to start a new message with the right headers — it just needs refactoring into a little “start a new message” function.

Comment: This is actually the way I ended up doing it ;)